# Form: Onload a script, wait 2 sec, then load next

Tags: html, forms, button

I have a page that automatically gets the position, and fills it into a form.

```
</script>
<body onload="getLocation();">
```

Then i have to wait 2 sec, and push a button to convert position to real address.

```
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Reverse Geocode">
```

How can i trigg the button automatically or remove the button and have the trigging automatically-

With a time delay of 2 sec?

Code:

```
 function getLocation(){

    if(navigator.geolocation){
       // timeout at 60000 milliseconds (60 seconds)
       var options = {timeout:60000};
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation, errorHandler, options);
    }
    else{
       alert("Sorry, browser does not support geolocation!");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to CLICK the button after 2 seconds of Page Load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `setTimeout()` function to run a function after a defined number of milliseconds. In your case,

```
function getLocation(){
  if(navigator.geolocation){
    var options = {timeout:60000};
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation, errorHandler, options);

    setTimeout(
      function(){ 
        document.getElementById("submit").click(); //Click the Button
      }, 
      2000 // 2000 milliseconds = 2 seconds
    );
  }

  else{
    alert("Sorry, browser does not support geolocation!");
  }
}
```

The `DOM` `click()` method is used to virtually click the button with JavaScript.

Comment: So I put it between -  function getLocation(){ and 

            if(navigator.geolocation){ ?

Comment: @Bergum Where within the function do you want to `click()` the button?

Comment: @Bergum Please accept my answer if it helped you (by clicking the *tick* beside my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for 'setTimeout' function:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  // your code
}, 3000);
```